# inno setup to browse and extract zip file at sepcific location

Tags: inno-setup

I want to enable users to browse and extract zip files at a specific location.

Requirements/steps:

1. Display welcome page
2. Next display browse button to select installation directory(`DisableDirPage=no`)
3. Next display browse button to select zip file(`JDK`)
4. Extract `JDK` zip file selected in step 3 at location selected in step 2, that means `JDK` should be extracted in installation directory that user selects in step 2

Problems with my code:

1. After the first step my code directly jump into 3rd step and then it goes to 2nd.
2. The code to extract zip is not working if I pass method name as the parameter. If I pass the hardcoded value of the location it works. I don't know pascal and it basically seems to be a syntax related issue.

---

[SETUP]

```
AppName=My Program
        AppVersion=1.5
        DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program
        DefaultGroupName=My Program
        UninstallDisplayIcon={app}\MyProg.exe
        DisableProgramGroupPage=no
        DisableWelcomePage=no
        DisableDirPage=no
        Compression=lzma2
        SolidCompression=yes
        OutputDir=userdocs:Inno Setup Examples Output
```

[Files]

```
Source: "{code:GetLicensePath}"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: external
Source: "7za.exe"; DestDir: "D:\authorized\Builds\Solo\"; Flags: deleteafterinstall;
```

[Icons]

```
Name: "{group}\My Program"; Filename: "{app}\MyProg.exe"
```

[Run]

```
Filename: D:\authorized\Builds\Solo\7za.exe; Parameters: "x ""{{Code:GetZipPath}}"" -o""{app}\"" * -r -aoa"; Flags: runhidden runascurrentuser;
```

[Code]

```
 var
   Page: TInputFileWizardPage;
   DataDir:String;

 procedure InitializeWizard();
 begin
   Page :=
     CreateInputFilePage(
       wpWelcome,
       'Select Zip File Location',
       'Where is your Zip file located?',
       'Select where Zip file is located, then click Next.');

   Page.Add(
     'Location of Zip file:',         
     '*.7z|*.rar|All files|*.*', 
     '.zip');  

 // Set initial value (optional)
 Page.Values[0] := ExpandConstant('{%USERPROFILE}\Downloads\setup.7z'); 
     ;                   
 end;



 function GetZipPath(Param: string): string;
 begin
   DataDir := Page.Values[0];

 end;
```

Could you help me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The order of your custom page is determined by the first argument of the `Create*` function. So change `wpWelcome` to `wpSelectDir`.
2. Why double `{{...}}` - That’s likely the problem. Also `code:` should be lowercase.
3. Your scripted constant function does not really return anything. It should be:

   ```
    Result := Page.Values[0];
   ```